# Wrong page headers in front matter

Tags: header-footer, lyx, front-matter

I am just finishing off my thesis and have run into the following problem. My front matter contains:

Table of Contents,
List of Tables,
List of Figures,
Nomenclature (renamed to List of Abbreviations in preamble)

Added by lyx and then an Abstract (2 pages) added manually. When I compile the pdf the “List of Figures” header continues to appear on the List of Abbreviations pages and the 2nd page of the abstract. Any idea how I can stop it?

```
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}

Title

\end{titlepage}

Disclaimer:

The work included in this thesis represent my own except where otherwise indicated. All relevant permissions have been obtained for figures obtained from published work.

Signature:

Name: 

Date:

Table of Contents
List of Tables
List of Figures
Nomenclature



Abstract

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}



Musculoskeletal tissue is prone ...

\mainmatter

1 Introduction

Musculoskeletal tissue,
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in another question. Change the lyx Nomeclature entry to ERT:

```
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\printnomenclature
\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: In addition to Kurt's important comment: Please post complete examples, not just fragments